# How we can get only that CSV headers, which have data in specific columns?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | -- | bcd | -- |
| edf | sdg | -- | rzh |

For Example: in row 1, Data is not available in Column B and Column D. so for row 1 header output should be Column A, Column C. Same in the row 2 Data is not available in Column C. so for row 2 header output should be Column A, Column B, Column D.

In this code I'm getting error like.
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject''

What should I do to get output?

```
string csvFilePath = "your_csv_file.csv";

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(csvFilePath))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
        {
            // Read the CSV records into a dynamic list
            var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();

            // Get the headers from the first record
            var headers = ((IDictionary<string, object>)records[0]).Keys.ToList();

            // Create a list to store headers with data
            var headersWithData = new List<string>();

            // Iterate through headers and check if any row in the column has data
            foreach (var header in headers)
            {
                if (records.Skip(1).Any(record => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(record[header]?.ToString())))
                {
                    headersWithData.Add(header);
                }
            }

            // Print the filtered column headers with data
            Console.WriteLine("Column Headers with Data:");
            foreach (var header in headersWithData)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(header);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It sounds like a very simple filter. What difficulty do you have?

Comment: What is `CsvReader` and `CsvConfiguration`?

Comment: @Enigmativity https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/

Comment: Are the `"--"` meant to be `"--"`, `""`, or `null`?

Comment: Don't use `dynamic`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as simple as doing this:

```
string[][] results =
    File
        .ReadAllLines(csvFilePath)
        .Select(x => x.ParseCsvLine())
        .Select(x => x.Where(y => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(y)).ToArray())
        .ToArray();
```

`ParseCsvLine` turns a `string` into a `stringp[]` from the CSV.

Comment: I'm geting one error => Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject''.

in `if (records.Skip(1).Any(record => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(record[header]?.ToString())))`

Comment: @Brown - Then answer my comments on your question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as you were treating `dynamic` datatype as `IDictionary` datatype.
Type casting of the data will solve your issue.

```
// Iterate through headers and check if any row in the column has data
foreach (var header in headers)
{
    if (records.Skip(1).Any(record => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(((IDictionary<string, object>)record)[header]?.ToString())))
    {
        headersWithData.Add(header);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the right idea.  Loop through the records, then cast your `dynamic` record to `IDictionary<string, object>`.  Use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/) to find items whose column values are not `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and then select the `Key`, which is the column header. Use `string.Join` to join the returned `IEnumerable<string>` of the header names that contain the data for that row.

```cs
using (var reader = new StringReader("Column A,Column B,Column C,Column D\nabc,,bcd,\nedf,sdg,,rzh"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
{
    // Read the CSV records into a dynamic list
    var records = csv.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();

    // Create a list to store headers with data
    var headersWithData = new List<string>();

    // Iterate through each record and check if a column has data   
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        var rowHeaders = ((IDictionary<string, object>)record)
            .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Value?.ToString()))
            .Select(item => item.Key);
            
        headersWithData.Add(string.Join(",", rowHeaders));      
    }
    
    // Print the filtered column headers with data
    Console.WriteLine("Column Headers with Data:");
    foreach (var header in headersWithData)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(header);
    }
}
```